# Displaying custom checkout billing field on email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, I want to add some custom fields on checkout which will be displayed under the **billing** section on the e-mail confirmation. 
My custom fields and their values, shown on the checkout form and on the order page on back end (WooCommerce -> Orders). So far everything works great.

**The problem is that the e-mail that i receive does not contain the custom fields and their values.**

Code shown below:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
    function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
        $fields['billing']['billing_field_testing'] = array(
            'label'     => __('TestingField', 'woocommerce'),
            'placeholder'   => _x('TestingField', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
            'clear'     => true
             );
        return $fields;
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
    function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order)
    {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('TestingField').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_field_testing', true ) . '</p>';
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:** To display your custom checkout field in email notifications below the billing address, use this function hooked in **`woocommerce_email_customer_details`** action hook with a priority above 20:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','add_custom_checkout_field_to_emails_notifications', 25, 4 );
function add_custom_checkout_field_to_emails_notifications( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    $output = '';
    $billing_field_testing = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_billing_field_testing', true );

    if ( !empty($billing_field_testing) )
        $output .= '<div><strong>' . __( "Some text:", "woocommerce" ) . '</strong> <span class="text">' . $billing_field_testing . '</span></div>';

    echo $output;
}
```

The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customize email templates under woocommerce/templates/emails/ to your-theme/woocommerce/emails/

Youc an override whatever template you want end add custom field there.

Alternatively, you can also add them using hook from following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3 );

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['meta_key'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Label' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, 'meta_key', true ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
```